# Creating Table with Table Name defined by a parameter derived into Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I am trying to run a procedure which creates a table, and the table name is based on a parameter passed to the procedure.

Here is the Procedure, I have already created:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Creating_Table]
@number varchar(8)
AS

CREATE TABLE CONCAT(table_name,@number) (
column1 int,
column2 int,
column3 int  
    );
GO
```

Is there a working implementation for this?

Comment: You would need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for that.

Comment: Need to use dynamic sql `EXEC('create cmd here')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dynamic SQL** will helps you.

Creating tables Dynamically will be a risky thing.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Creating_Table]
@number varchar(8)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(1000),@TableName VARCHAR(100)
    SELECT @TableName = 'Table_'+ @number
    SELECT @Query = '

    CREATE TABLE '+@TableName+' (
        column1 int,
        column2 int,
        column3 int  
     );'

    EXEC (@Query)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you could use a fixed "template table" which is renamed

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Creating_Table] @number VARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @number IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END

    DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(128) = 'table_name' + @number;


    --table already exists, return
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + @tablename) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END

    --if template does not exist, create it
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.template_table') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE dbo.template_table
        (
            column1 int,
            column2 int,
            column3 int  
        );  

    END

    --rename template
    EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.template_table', @tablename, N'OBJECT';

    RETURN;
END
```